# SQL Count with join are returning double results

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, "event" and "soundType". I am trying to count the number of event with specific soundType. 
This is my request :

```
SELECT Count(*) AS nb 
FROM   event 
       INNER JOIN soundtype 
               ON event.id = soundtype.eventid 
WHERE  ( soundtype.NAME = 'pop' 
          OR soundtype.NAME = 'rock' ) 
       AND ( event.partytype = 'wedding' 
              OR event.partytype = 'Corporate evening' 
              OR event.partytype = 'birthday' )
```

Example of tables below:

event Table

```
id      userId    partyType
----------------------------
249       30      birthday
250       30      wedding
```

SoundType Table

```
id      evenId    name
-----------------------
1       249       pop
2       249       rock
3       250       pop
```

The result

```
nb
---
3
```

The result i expect

```
nb
---
2
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try chaning select count to select star to understand which rows you are getting.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that `exists` is more efficient than `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb 
FROM event e
WHERE e.partytype IN ('wedding', 'Corporate evening' , 'birthday') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM soundtype st
              WHERE st.eventid = e.id AND
                    st.NAME IN ('pop', 'rock') 
             ) ;
```

Your problem is (presumably) arising because some events have multiple sound types.  You just need to match one of them.  Multiplying out all the rows just to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is inefficient, when `EXISTS` (or `IN`) prevents the duplicates in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You count all the resulting records. But you need to count **different** events. So use `distinct`

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct event.id) AS nb 
FROM event 
INNER JOIN soundType ON event.id = soundType.eventId 
WHERE soundType.name in('pop', 'rock')
AND event.partyType in('wedding', 'Corporate evening', 'birthday')
```